# Check username, password - Login Form using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I want to create a login form with array data UsersData.js:

```
const users = [
  {
    username: 'admin1',
    password: '12345678'
  },
  {
    username:'admin2',
    password:'012345678'
  }
];
```

and Login.js looks something like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { users } from 'UsersData';

  function Login() {
      const [data, setData] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
      });
          
      const {uname, pass} = data;
      const checkUser = () => {
        const usercheck = users.find(user => (user.username === uname && user.password === pass));
        if(usercheck) {
          console.log("Login successful");
        }else {
          console.log("Wrong password or username");
        }
        // console.log(uname);
        console.log(usercheck);
      }

      const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setData({...data, [e.target.name]:[e.target.value]})
      }
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        checkUser();
        console.log(checkUser());
      }

    return (
      <div className="login-bg">
        <div className="card">
          <form className='loginForm'
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
          <div className="input-text">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                value={uname}
                placeholder="Username"
                aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required
                onChange={changeHandler}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="input-text">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={pass}
              placeholder="Password"
              aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
            
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-warning btn-block">
                Login
              </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
export default Login;
```

So the above code only check whether the username and password fields entered in the form match the name and password of single record in the array of objects of UsersData.js the above code is working fine.I wrote checkUser() function but the result is not true.

Please show an instance of how it is done. Sorry, I'm new to ReactJS so I'm a bit confused, hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Just to make clear: You are aware that password validation at the frontend is completely useless ... And `checkUser()` does not return anything, so its result is `undefined` add `return usercheck !== undefined` as last statement to return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic here is also not correct this is how the event handled must be

```
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const users = [
  {
    username: 'admin1',
    password: '12345678'
  },
  {
    username:'admin2',
    password:'012345678'
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  });
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setData({...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  const checkUser = () => {
    const usercheck = users.find(user => (user.username === data.username && user.password === data.password));
    if(usercheck) {
      console.log("Login successful");
    }else {
      console.log("Wrong password or username");
    }
    // console.log(uname);
    console.log(usercheck);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
checkUser(users)
  }, [data.username, data.password])

  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="input-text">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                value={data.username}
                placeholder="Username"
                aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required
                onChange={changeHandler}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="input-text">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={data.password}
              placeholder="Password"
              aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
            
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your method is very reasonable.

Comment: Check this out this should solve your problem now ? just instead of using the useEffect rather use the onsubmit and invoke the checkUser

Comment: yes, i know where i went wrong. Thank you, kodamace

Answer (score 0):

Hey autumnha So with the way you are destructuring firstly needs to be the values that you are pulling from data obj

Let me know if this is what your goal is ?

```
const { username, password } = data
```

we now have the local component state of username and data

```
const checkUser = (users) => {
        const usercheck = users.find(user => (user.username === username 
        && user.password === password))
         return usercheck ? console.log('successfully logged in') : 
        console.log('wrong credentials')
 }
```

we then invoke the function

```
checkUser(users)
```

Comment: I want check whether the username and password fields entered in the form match the name and password of single record in the array of objects of User.js. 
I tried following your solution. But the result is wrong.

Comment: Yeah also this is recommended to be done on the backend and you have to validate the users according to the details they send through

Comment: Try user Object.keys(checkUser).length ? 1 ?

Comment: did you update the uname values and pass values in the form ?

Comment: oh no, i'm sorry :v

Comment: @autumnha <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                value={username}
                placeholder="Username"
                aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required
                onChange={changeHandler}
              />

and then also for password :D

Comment: check the other answer i sent you were adding an array each time and not the targeted value I posted the correct solution for your handleChange function above

Comment: @autumnha I pasted the code in the top and everything works please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use map() and some() to achieve that goal. As you are checking if one of the user is in the array, that will generate an array with true, and false, like [false, false, true], etc.

Therefore, the most straightforward solution is to map through the users with your input values and then check authentication by some().

```
const onCheck = () => {
  const {uname, pass} = data;
  const isAuthenticated = users.map(user => user.username === uname && user.password === pass);

  return isAuthenticated.some();
}


if(onCheck()) {
   console.log("Login successful");
}else {
   console.log("Wrong password or username");
}
```

Comment: Imagine we had a large list of users do you not think its better to find the first user in the list instead of iterating over all of them ? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const getDataLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RegItems'));
        console.log("getDataLogin---------->",getDataLogin);
            const loginSuccess = getDataLogin.find(user => user.userName === userLogin.userName && user.password === userLogin.password);
        return loginSuccess ? console.log('successfully logged in') :
            console.log('wrong username and password');
        console.log(loginSuccess);
    };
```